# What is the encoding can be used in XSLT to support only basic Latin alphabet characters?

Tags: xslt, encoding, xslt-2.0

I am searching for the correct encoding type need to be used in XSLT when process my XML.

My need is:

Output text file **do not accept any special characters or UTF8**. 
Alphabet logic utilized which only support the modern English alphabet is a Latin-based alphabet consisting of 26 letters –  the same letters that are found in the Basic modern Latin alphabet.

I tried to use the **encoding="ISO 8859-1"** , **encoding="ISO 8859-15"**.

Can some one tell me the correct encoding if above are wrong

Thanks,
Jagan

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you need.  It _sounds_ like what you need to do is to sanitize your output, **in your XSLT code**, before it ever gets to the output file.

Comment: You can try the [Windows-1252 charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Answer (score 2):

Like @EiríkrÚtlendi suggested in the comments; sanitize/check your output in the XSLT.

You can create a function with a single parameter that checks for an invalid character...

**XML Input**

```
<elem>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</elem>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:so="StackOverflow Example">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="elem">
    <xsl:value-of select="so:out(.)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="so:out">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:if test="matches($str,'[^\p{L}]')">
      <xsl:message terminate="yes">
        <xsl:value-of
          select="
          concat('Invalid character in &quot;',
          $str, '&quot;.')"
        />
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Text Output**

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

If you add any other character to the `elem` element in the input, you'll get the following message (I added a space to make it fail):

```
Invalid character in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
```

You could also check it character by character...

```
<xsl:function name="so:out">
  <xsl:param name="str"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints($str)">
    <xsl:if test="matches(codepoints-to-string(.),'[^\p{L}]')">
      <xsl:message terminate="yes">
        <xsl:value-of
          select="
            concat('Invalid character (&quot;',
            codepoints-to-string(.),
            '&quot;) in &quot;',
            $str, '&quot;.')"
        />
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
</xsl:function>
```

which would produce the message:

```
Invalid character (" ") in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
```